# Articles définis féminin. Y a-t-il toujours élision devant une voyelle ou un h muet ?

Tags: grammaire, articles, articles-definis

I ran into this exercise where I have to chose between *articles definis féminins ou masculins*.

```
...
IV. Le ventre
V l'industrie
...
```

In Catalan,

- *la* + mot qui commence par une voyelle ou h ne s'élide pas

Does the same rule apply in French?

Is *l'industrie* correct, or has to be written as *la industrie*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voici la règle de base pour l'article défini féminin singulier et aussi pour l'article masculin.

> ([Français Facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-93338.php)) On utilise le L' devant un nom masculin ou féminin commençant par une voyelle ou par H.
> Tous les mots commençant par H ne sont pas toujours introduits par L'.
> Exemples :
> Masculin : Le papillon → Les papillons - L'arbre → Les arbres - L'hiver → Les hivers -Le haricot → Les haricots
> Féminin : La fourmi → Les fourmis - L'abeille → Les abeilles - L'histoire → Les histoires - La harpe → Les harpes

Voici maintenant ce qui va vous permettre de décider quel h nécessite l'apostrophe. Il y a deux sortes de h, le h aspiré, pour lequel rien ne change, et le h muet  pour lequel l'apostrophe est nécessaire (élision). Voir cette [page aidenet](http://www.aidenet.eu/grammaire01ac.htm).

Voici une courte liste des mots dont le h est muet (due à aidenet).

habileté
habillage
habit
habitacle
habitat
habitude
haleine
hallali
hallucination
haltère     hameçon
harmonie
hebdomadaire
hébergement
hébreu
hectare
hégémonie
hélice
héliogravure
hallucination   hégémonie hélium
hémicycle
hémophile
héraldique
herbe
hérédité
héritage
héroïne
héroïsme    herpès hésitation
hétérogène
hippique
histoire
homme
horodateur
huissier
hypoténuse
...

Answer (score 1):

Like Italian (*l'industria*), French elides the feminine definite article final *A* (the *A* is not pronounced and replaced by an apostrophe).

> *La industrie → L'industrie
> *La âme → L'âme
> *La amie → L'amie
> *La eau → L'eau

If the word starts with an *H*, the elision is done when the it is *muet* (muted, silent).

1. Examples of *H muet*:

> L'horreur
> L'huile
> L'humeur
> L'humanité
> L'héroïne  (curiously, the *H* is *aspiré* in *le héros*)

2. But not when it is an *[H aspiré](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_aspir%C3%A9)* (aspirated):

> La hauteur
> La hulotte

3. Undecided:

> Le hiatus / L'hiatus

In Catalan, contrarily to what is stated in the question, elision can be observed when the leading vowel of the noun is accented:

> **La ànima* → *L'ànima*
> **La aigua* → *L'aigua*
> **La amic* → *L'amic*

Otherwise, the article stays unchanged:

> *La indústria*

In Spanish, a slightly different method is used. The feminine definite article (*la*) is substituted by the masculine one (*el*), so the effect is almost identical:

> **La alma* → *El alma*
> **La agua* → *El agua*

Like Catalan, it is not done when the initial vowel does not carry the tonic accent:

> *La amiga*
> *La industría*

Comment: L'apostrophe n'existe pas à l'espgnol.

Comment: @SNR Oui, l'apostrophe n'est pas utilisée pour marquer l'élision en espagnol, mais il existe un phénomène très similaire. Je viens de remanier ma réponse pour l'expliquer. Ta question affirme aussi que le catalan ne connaît pas l'élision avec apostrophe, ce qui est inexact.